# Android ImageView Extra Spacing

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I integrated a picture into my app page using ImgaeView and now there is excess space to the right of the image.
`android:adjustViewBounds="true"` **Is not the answer**
**It does not fix the spacing issue**
Here's the code:

```
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/f2lcase2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/f2lcase2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Common F2L Cases" />
```

I don't have enough rep to post the pic but there is a large amount of space between the image and the text.
**Thanks!**
**Edit**
Here is the full XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.cube.F2l" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Common F2L Cases"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/f2lcase2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/f2lcase2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Common F2L Cases" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/f2lcase3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/f2lcase3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use  `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your views are going to repeat many times, so you can use ListView for that.Also since your image is static, you can simply set Left Drawable of your TextView. So below is the layout for one row of the ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourImage"
    android:text="Common F2L Cases" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey this method worked perfectly for me! Now I am making a different list in a different activity but the pictures in the TextView are too small. Can I change the size of the Image?

Comment: you might be using smaller size pictures

Comment: well, it's great.. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this !

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/f2lcase2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/f2lcase2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Common F2L Cases" />
```

Comment: Almost! When I do this it distorts the square image so it fills up the would-be empty space.

Comment: @ Benjamin Spiegel .... If so try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` ... instead of ``android:scaleType="fitXY"``

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code it may help you:

```
public class MyImage extends ImageView {

public MyImage(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

    if (d != null) {
        // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
  }
 }
```

In your xml do like this:

```
    <com.exmple.myview.MyImage
            android:id="@+id/ImageView3_Left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_2"

            ></com.exmple.myview.MyImage>
```

that's it. This will solve your plroblem.

Comment: Do I have to make a new class for the java? I'm just not sure how to implement this

Comment: I used this code and added some things in the XML and it looks like box around the picture is smaller which is great. Unfortunately, the textview is not immediately following the imageview even though it should be

Comment: put image and textview in a linear layout

Comment: They are in a tablerow in a tablelayout in a linearlayout

Comment: SO what is the problem

Comment: There is space between the image and text. when I make another app and use this code it works.

Comment: I would but I dont have enough rep to upvote and also my problem hasn't been fixed